# Stopping Hostile Threads in JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, security, jvm

I'm writing a server, which may be running hostile code.  To prevent an attacker from throwing a thread into an infinite loop, I want to enforce a one-second execution time limit.

An `InterruptedException` can be caught inside an infinite loop, thus allowing an attacker to retain control of the thread.  Thus `Thread.interrupt()` is not an acceptable solution.

My current implementation prevents hostile threads from acquiring any resources (including locks), uses `Thread.stop()` to terminate execution, and reverts any changes made by the thread.  My main complaint is that it uses the deprecated `Thread.stop()` method; I don't like using deprecated code.

I'm wondering if there is a more industry-accepted solution, short of launching/killing an entirely new JVM, which would have too much overhead for my purposes.

Comment: Run the untrusted code in a language that supports cheap sandboxes. Lua is nice for that, but I don't know if there is an implementation of it for the JVM. Btw how do you prevent it from acquiring resources or using dangerous APIs?

Comment: I don't think limiting a hostile thread to 1 second does anything good.  1 second is a few billion instructions.

Comment: I use a combination of an extremely strict access controller and some bytecode manipulation.  For the type of calls I'm considering, 1 second is a generous, but reasonable restriction.  I'm just trying to avoid someone maliciously launching bunches of threads that will never complete.

Comment: @Jim, if you are going to run totally unknown code, you need a separate process. No other way around, -XX:+TieredCompilation mitigates the issue, you might want to keep JVM on a ram-disk or at least SSD to speed up the start-up too. Also feel free to use Thread.stop(), if you can do `Thread.suspend()` walk the stack and determine it's ok to `stop()`. Yet, there are a lot ways to (maliciously) cause DoS even w/ the strictest SecurityManager. So a solution is running the unsecure code into a separate process (or multiple) and forcibly kill if it doesn't respond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to kill a thread is to use a separate process and kill that process.  Thread.stop() throws a ThreadDeath error which can be caught and ignored. i.e. `catch(Throwable t) {}`

For more details on what Thread.stop() actually does [Does Thread.stop() really stop a Thread?](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/06/threadstop-really-stop-thread.html)

Comment: I've some success instrumenting the loaded bytecode to catch ThreadDead and rethrow it.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about ThreadDeath, and java.lang.Error is already on my whitelist, so my initial solution is starting to feel too unsafe.  Thanks for all the feedback!  I'm thinking I should create some worker-processes, which I can delegate tasks to, and kill when necessary.  JVM overhead and the additional serialization will be very unfortunate, but I don't see a safe alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot guarantee that a thread can be stopped as several blocking methods (like sockets) do not respond to interrupt().

I would suggest a very strict security manager so you can be absolutely certain that the malicious code is sandboxed.  If you need to be certain then consider a special classloader which ensures that only valid operations are being done.

Comment: `I would suggest a very strict security manager so you can be **absolutely certain**`, impossible in java unless the bytecode is instrumented.

Comment: but that doesn't prevent DoS like not-stopping threads that don't won't to be stopped.

Comment: Yes, I'm using an incredibly strict access controller and am doing bytecode manipulation to prevent many other operations.  The goal here is, as bestsss observed, to prevent DoS like not-stopping threads.